# I'm using C++ and need help identifying an error in my code

Tags: c++

My outfile seems to be writing correctly but the infile is reading garbage value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int count;

ifstream infile;
infile.open("accounts.txt");

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("accounts.txt");

cout<<"Read from file"<<endl;
infile>>count;
cout<<count<<endl;
cout<<"Write in file"<<endl;
outfile<<count;
cout<<count;

infile.close();
outfile.close();
return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Read from file
4255273
Write in file
4255273
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is attempting to open and access the *same* file, concurrently, as both an *input* and *output* stream. This will not work!

You should rearrange your code so that you open it for input, do the input, then close it. Only then can you re-open it for output.

Here's a suggestion:

```c
int main()
{
    int count;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("accounts.txt");  // First, open for input...
    cout << "Read from file" << endl;
    infile >> count;              // ... and read the data
    cout << count << endl;
    infile.close();               // Done reading: close it!

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("accounts.txt"); // Now, open for output...
    cout << "Write in file" << endl;
    outfile << count;             // ... do the output...
    cout << count;
    outfile.close();              // ... and close it.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I separately opened and closed the files using the same text file and it works fine now. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: There's an alternative by using a 'generic' `fstream` opened in both input *and* output mode, but that would require some extra tricks. Something like this: `fstream file("accounts.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);` - see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/66306/) for a discussion of a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Adrian's answer. Reading and Writing happens where the current file pointer is and it advances with each read/write. In your particular case, you're clobbering those pointers as they point to same file, leading to garbage values being printed out.

Comment: Actually, I *think* (but I'm still looking for an authoritative confirmation) that the second `.open()` call will, essentially, close the `ifstream` from the first call.

Comment: @AdrianMole Nope. If the stream is already associated with a file (i.e., it is already open), calling this function fails. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

Comment: I saw that reference but it's not relevant here, as the `ofstream outfile` is ***not*** (yet) associated with a file. It's the other way round: the **file** is already associated with a (different) **stream**.

Comment: Ah, I see. Apologies, you're right. It could be possible. Please let me know once you get confirmation.

Comment: I thought this would make a good new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59589175/10871073