# Is opening the SAME file in two different fstreams Undefined Behaviour?

Tags: c++, fstream, undefined-behavior

This [recently asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59588564/10871073) has raised another interesting issue, as discussed in the [comments to one of its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59588652/10871073).

To summarize: the OP there was having issues with code like that below, when subsequently attempting to read *and* write data from/to the two streams 'concurrently':

```cpp
ifstream infile;
infile.open("accounts.txt");

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("accounts.txt");
```

Although the issue, in itself, was successfully resolved, it has raised a question to which I cannot find an authoritative answer (and I've made some quite extensive searches of Stack Overflow and the wider web).

It is very clearly stated what happens when calling the `open()` method of a **stream** that is already associated with a **file** ([cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/)), but what I cannot find an answer to is what happens when (as in this case) the **file** is already associated with a (different) **stream**.

> If the stream is already associated with a file (i.e., it is already
>   open), calling this function fails.

I can see several possible scenarios here:

1. The second open call will fail and any attempted writes to it will also fail (but that is *not* the case in the cited question).
2. The second open call will 'override' the first, effectively closing it (this *could* explain the issues encountered in said code).
3. Both streams remain open but enter into a 'mutual clobbering' match regarding their internal file pointers and buffers.
4. We enter the realm of undefined (or implementation-defined) behaviour.

*Note that, as the first `open()` call is made by an input stream, the operating system will not necessarily 'lock' the file, as it probably would for an output stream.*

So, does anyone have a definitive answer to this? Or a citation from the Standard (cppreference will be 'acceptable' if nothing more authoritative can be found)?

Comment: "cppreference will suffice"? In my experience, this is rarely the case. The subtle details in the standards are quite often not found on that site.

Comment: @paxdiablo A good point well made - see (minor) edit!

Comment: Interestingly, stream opens contain the text "as if by calling `fopen`" so defer to the relevant C standard. Not sure that helps that much since a cursory glance at C11 also gives no indication as to what defined behaviour should ensue if you open the same file with two different `FILE*` variables :-)

Comment: Nothing is said in the C standard. On posix compliant OSes (Linux), you will not have any trouble, `fopen` will call the `open` system call which will create an `open file description` for each streams. Everything will work as expected.

Comment: @Oliv But that just defers to what "work as expected" means: the `ostream.open()` call (== `fopen` in "w" mode) will *discard* the contents of the file that was previously used in the `istream.open()` call, so can one "expect" to make valid reads therefrom?

Comment: Well, it should work according to common sense. First, opening mode should be appropriate (non exclusive, not truncating) and then not working on common part of the file. For example, if `outfile` append content at the end and `infile` read pre-existing content, it should work fine. However, it would hard to predict when reading would reach the end of file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`basic_filebuf::open` (and all things that depend on it, like `fstream::open`) has no statement about what will happen in this case. A filesystem may allow it or it may not.

What the standard says is that, if the file successfully opens, then you can play with it in accord with the interface. And if it doesn't successfully open, then there will be an error. That is, the standard allows a filesystem to permit it or forbid it, but it doesn't say which must happen. The implementation can even randomly forbid it. Or forbid you from opening any files in any way. All are (theoretically) valid.

Comment: The Standard does not require that an implementation mirror the behavior of the underlying OS, but instead regards such things as outside its jurisdiction.  If, for example, an OS may allow a file to be opened twice for append, using two different paths, with semantics that everything given to the OS will be written to the file in sequence, an implementation targeting that OS might pass all output direct to the OS, or might add its own buffering to each stream, or the implementation might query the file position before each write and behave any way it sees fit if it notices that it changes.

Answer (score 2):

C implementations exist for many different platforms, whose underlying file systems may handle such corner cases differently.  For the Standard to mandate any particular corner-case behavior would have made the language practical only on platforms whose file systems behave in such fashion.  Instead, the Standard regards such issues as being outside its jurisdiction (i.e. to use its own terminology, "Undefined Behavior").  That doesn't mean that implementations whose target OS offers useful guarantees shouldn't make such guarantees to programs when practical, but implementation designers are presumed to know more than the Committee about how best to serve their customers.

On the other hand, it may sometime be helpful for an implementation *not* to expose the underlying OS behavior.  On an OS that doesn't have a distinct "append" mode, for example, but code needing an "open for append" could do an "open existing file for write" followed by "seek to end of file", an attempt to open two streams for appending to the same file could result in data corruption when one stream writes part of a file, and the other stream then rewrites that same portion.  It may be helpful for an implementation that detects that condition to either inject its own logic to either ensure smooth merging of the data or block the second open request.  Either course of action might be better, depending upon an application's purpose, but--as noted above--the choice is outside the Standard's jurisdiction.

Comment: "*to use its own terminology, "Undefined Behavior"*" That's not really true. UB is within the jurisdiction of the standard; it's an explicit statement that something has no reliable behavior. By contrast, whether a filesystem can open the same file or not is more a matter of the filesystem than of the standard. It isn't UB; it's "you have to check to see if it opened".

Comment: According to the authors of the Standard, "Undefined behavior... also identifies areas of possible conforming language extension: the implementor may augment the language by providing a definition of the officially undefined behavior."  Why would the authors of the Standard suggest such a thing if they didn't intend that implementations do so in cases their customers would find useful?  And what term does C99 use for an action whose meaning under C89 had been defined, identically on all implementations for common platforms, but whose C89 spec may have been inappropriate for weird ones?

Comment: Wall of text. What is your conclusion? What is your point? What are you saying? What is your answer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: The Standard would allow an implementer to behave in whatever fashion would best serve the implementer's customer (or, if the implementer doesn't care about that, whatever fashion the implementer sees fit for whatever other reason).  Which behavior is best in any given situation would depend upon many factors about which customers and compiler writers would know far more than the Committee ever could.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: It is "undefined behavior" in the sense that the authors of the Standard intended the term, but not in the way that some compiler writers are prone to interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

To me, this falls even out of the 'implementation defined' field. The very same code will have different behaviour depending of the underlying filesystem or OS (some OSes forbid to open a file twice).

Answer (score 1):

No.

Such a scenario is not discussed by the standard.

It's not even managed by the implementation (your compiler, standard library implementation etc).

The stream ultimately asks the operating system for access to that file in the desired mode, and it's up to the operating system to decide whether that access shall be granted at that time.

A simple analogy would be your program making some API call to a web application over a network. Perhaps the web application does not permit more than ten calls per minute, and returns some error code if you attempt more than that. But that doesn't mean your program has undefined behaviour in such a case.

Comment: Even if the OS defines the semantics, the implementation may inject its own semantics however it sees fit.  For example, it could add logic so that if it sees the same path opened twice for append, both will use the same set of buffers, or so that repeated attempts to open the same path will fail if the OS would otherwise behave in a way that might sometimes cause data corruption.

Comment: @supercat It could. It doesn't, though.

Comment: What could?  I don't know of any particular implementations that do that, but an implementation's whose customers need to use code written for an OS with different semantics from what the new target requires might quite plausibly include emulation logic to achieve the necessary semantics.

Comment: @supercat What is your point? Are you suggesting a change to the answer? If so, what is it? If not, why do you  comment? Not an insult, just confused as to the purpose of your comment.

Comment: It is common for implementations to map stdio functions fairly straightforwardly to OS functions in situations where that makes sense, but one would often need to look at implementation's documentation, and not just that of the OS to know what to expect in tricky situations where there's no one clear "best" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I open the zip file as stream twice.The zip file contains some XML files.

```
std::ifstream("filename") file;
zipstream *p1 = new zipstream(file);
zipstream *p2 = new zipstream(file);
p1->getNextEntry();
auto p3 = p1.rdbuf();
autp p4 = p2.rdbuf();
```

Then see p3 address = p4 address, but the member variables are different between them. Such as _IGfirst.

The contents of one of the XML files are as follows:

```
<test>
    <one value="0.00001"/>
</test>
```

When the contents of file are read in two thread at the same time.error happend.

```
string One = p1.getPropertyValue("one");
// one = "0001two"
```