# Write to a file in the middle of two writings by another ofstream

Tags: c++

In the following program the output is: AAABBBAppended more.
You can notice that  "1111" is lost.
Is there a way to save the "1111" without changing the implementation of class A.
This question is because where A coming from a 3rd party library.
I can see their code but can not modify it. The constructor of A is writing
somewhat more than desired. I know exactly how many bytes they are writing.

```
#include <fstream> 
class A {
    std::ofstream os1;
public:
    A(std::string& str)
    {
        //std::ofstream 
        //os1.open(str.c_str(), std::trunc);
        os1.open(str, std::ios::trunc);
        if (os1.bad())
        {
            os1 << "Writing failed.." << endl;
            os1.close();
        }
        os1 << "AAA";
        os1 << "BBB";

    }

    void write_more()
    {
        os1 << "Appended more.";
    }

    void close()
    {
        os1.close();
    }
};

    void write_os1_os2_os1()
    {
        std::string str("\\temp\\a.txt");
        A a(str);
    
        std::ofstream os2(str, std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
        if (os2.bad())
        {
            os2 << "Writing failed.." << endl;
            os2.close();
        }
        os2.seekp(5);//position to overwrite last two bytes 
        os2 << "1111";//overwrite last two bytes plus some more data  
        os2.close();
        
        a.write_more();
        a.close();
    
        return;
    }
```

Comment: So you're trying to open the same file for writing twice at the same time?

Comment: Opening the same file twice in different streams at the same time is... Not a good idea. Just don't do it. Some reading: [Is opening the SAME file in two different fstreams Undefined Behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59589175/4581301)

Comment: Have you considered passing a `std::ofstream&` to your constructor rather than a file name, and then opening the file _once_?

Comment: @chris Yes. Not sure even it is possible. Yet to read article sent by user4581301

Comment: @chris The A is coming from a commercial 3rd party. Their constructor only takes name.

Comment: Can't think of any decent, portable and non-abusive way to get into the middle of that file. Can think of a couple abusive ones, though. For example: https://godbolt.org/z/TPvnWoEaf If possible, let the sucker finish and close the file and then open, parse, and edit.

Comment: If a particular file needs accessed shared between two (or more) streams, it needs to be opened in a way that allows sharing.   Although a number of modern operating systems support opening for shared access, standard C and C++ do not (they default to every non-reading stream having exclusive access).  If your program is limited to an OS that allows shared access, that *may* be supported by (compiler/library specific) extensions - but then you'll need to modify every function that opens the particular file (i.e. if you can't change the class `A`, you're probably hosed).

Comment: *"My output is: AAABBBAppended more."* One sentence into your question and you've already lost me. Well, more accurately, at this point I have no idea is this output is good, bad, or out in left field. You should write your question as if the people reading it cannot read your mind. Start by telling us (at a high level) what your code is supposed to do so that when you describe your output, we can appreciate its significance. (See also [ask].)

Comment: Your title says "an ofstream" (singular). The text of your question does not mention "ofstream". Yet a key aspect of your code is that there are **two** `ofstream` objects, one you control and one private to the third-party class. I can grok the downvotes. Legit question, but the presentation leaves a lot to be desired.